# jquery: Find first element by attribute

Tags: jquery, html, webforms

I have a list with categories on my left side on the webpage, and a list with items on the right side. The list with items have an attribute called cat, and the values are numbers.

Clicking on the category should scroll me to the first item with the same categoryid.

Any tips? :)

Here is the html:

```
asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repCategory" OnItemDataBound="CategoryItemRepeater">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul class="menuListUl">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <div id="catItem" runat="server"></div>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>


 <div id="menuList">
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repFooditems" OnItemDataBound="MenuItemRepeater">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="menuItem" id="menuItem" runat="server">
                        <div runat="server" class="itemNumber" id="ItemId"></div>
                        <div runat="server" class="itemName" id="itemName"></div>
                        <div runat="server" class="itemDescription" id="itemDescriptionLbl"></div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

        </div>
```

**Codebehind:**

Categorylist:

```
var lbl = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("catItem");

lbl.Attributes.Add("catId",""+rest.CategoryId);
```

ItemList:

```
var menuItem = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("menuItem");
            menuItem.Attributes.Add ("cat","cat"+item.Item.Category.FirstOrDefault().CategoryId);
```

jquery:

```
$('.menuListUl li div').bind('click', function ()
        {
            var catId = $(this).attr('catid'); //The categoryid on the element clicked.


            // Now: find the first element with the same cat id

            var element = ""; The element found.

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: element.offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will select you the elements with 'foobar' as the catid. It seems to be this what you want right?

```
$('.menuListUl li div[catid="foobar"]')
```

Comment: Thats perfect :) Thanks! Gonna accept the answer as soon as i can

Comment: Actually. This will get the element in the category list, while i need the first item in the item list.

Comment: @sindrem you can do either $('.menuListUl li div[catid="foobar"]')[0] or $('.menuListUl li div[catid="foobar"]').first()