# Using jQuery to select first elements with distinct data-attribute

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I've got a `ul` of various items which can have one of several possible `data-attribute` values, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="li1" data-cat="one">test item
    <li id="li2" data-cat="one">test no 2
    <li id="li3" data-cat="two">test dummy
    <li id="li4" data-cat="three">test no 4
    <li id="li5" data-cat="three">more test
    <li id="li6" data-cat="three">test no 6
</ul>
```

*I'm attempting to use jQuery to select the first item of each distinct* `data-cat` *value* - so for this example, `li#li1`, `li#li3`, and `li#li4`. I've tried building an array of each element with the `data-attribute`, then sorting with `.unique` like this

```
var list = $( '[data-cat]' ).get();
listSorted = jQuery.unique( list );
$( listSorted ).addClass('active');
```

But the code just selected all elements ([see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nB3ru/4/))

I've found answers on SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397352/jquery-find-first-element-by-attribute) that come close, but they all seem to rely on knowing the `data-attribute` value beforehand and searching for that specific value. Is it possible to select the first element with a particular `data-cat` value without specifying the values beforehand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var cats = {};
var list = $( '[data-cat]' ).filter(function(){
    var category = $(this).data("cat");

    if(cats[category]){
        // category already accounted for, return false
        return false;   
    } else {
        // first of this category
        cats[category] = true;
        return true;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nB3ru/5/

Comment: Mines well just chain the `addClass` to the `filter` -> either way, +1

Comment: @tymeJV I did in the fiddle, just separated out the filter in the answer as I wasn't sure the addClass was really the endgoal.

Comment: @JamesMontagne way to make me feel like an idiot; this is great and looks much different than my poor attempts at solving the problem! You're right, the addClass wasn't really the objective, I just had it there to help me see what was being selected.